# Drush Make Non-existent project type on project metatags

Tags: drush

I am attempting to stream line the drush module DL process and it works great.  The Issue though is many modules are getting the error:

```
Non-existent project type  on project metatags
```

I attempted to google this but does not seem to be a known error.  Here is a copy of my make file (shortened)

```
;Use modules for Drupal 7
core = 7.x

;Drush api 2
api = 2

;Meta Tags
;http://drupal.org/project/metatags‎
projects[metatags][subdir] = contrib

;Also does not work with this:
;Views
;http://drupal.org/project/views‎
projects[] = views
```

Answer (score 1):

That is correct the project metatags doesn't exist it's actually metatag. Also you need to specify a core version as well.

```
api = 2
core = 7.x
projects[drupal][version] = "7.21"

;Meta Tags
;http://drupal.org/project/metatags‎
projects[metatag][subdir] = contrib

;Views
;http://drupal.org/project/views‎
projects[] = views
```

Running the above I get a Drupal 7.21 install with sites/all/modules/views and sites/all/modules/contrib/metatag

Comment: That worked for the metatag modules, but still did not work on views?  What version of drush are you running?

Comment: I'm using drush 5.9 in my VM.